# HTML5 creates div I cant edit with CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have some HTML as follows ( you can assume closing tags )

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-tab>
```

The problem is, when the DOM is created, the HTML5 tag creates a div which I cannot edit using CSS

It becomes as so

```
<ion-content>
   <div class="foo">
      <ion-tab>
```

I need to edit the CSS of the div whose class is "foo", however, if i change the CSS of foo, i change the CSS of all the classes using "foo".

How do I specifically apply CSS to that specific div when I dont create it myself?

Comment: The answer depends on the whole structure of your page: in which contex other .foo classes are placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the small amount off details you have given us, all I can do is refer to these [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

There are number off ways to style a specific element. All have been explained in detail in the link I have given you.

**Edit:** CSS Selectors explained in detail.

There are several ways to change the style of `<div class="foo">`.

- You could give the div an (extra) [#id](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) or [class](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp). This makes it able to apply certain styles, just you would do normally, to this specify element.
- Another option would be [`parent child {}`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) where you could style all the children within parent. *Note:* you could add '>/+/~' to be more specific of the place of child within parent.
- A third option would be to specify at what place the div is within its parent using [`:nth-child(n)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) or [`nth-of-type(n)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).

As I said before, there are many ways to style a specific element. Please take a look at the link I provided.

Comment: As lazy as that answer may have seemed, it did the trick for me! Thanks!

Comment: @Berendschot I kindly suggest you improve your answer so it does not relies on external links.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Although the question is solved. I've added some more details (and some 'worse resources').

Comment: @AllanMacmillan If this indeed solved your problem, please consider to accept the answer. That might help others aswell.